# How to change tty group on Linux (build with buildroot)

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, tty, buildroot, usergroups

I'm working on Linux Kernel 3.14.28 build with Buildroot for an embedded device.

In `/dev/`, all ttys are `root:root` and not `root:dialout` like a standard Linux. So it is not possible to access any ttyX without being logged as `root`.

How can I change the tty group permanently to `root:dialout`? I try to change it with chown command, but it became `root:root` again on reboot.

Comment: I'm using /devtmpfs and I do not know if there is a way to configure driver permission with it. There are solution with udev or static table for /dev management. But I would prefer to keep devtmpfs

Comment: With just devtmpfs, you cannot customize the permissions, except by running a shell script or something like that at boot time. Indeed the permissions do not persist accross reboots: devtmpfs is a virtual filesystem, so it only exist for the duration of the system life. If you want to customize permissions, you should use mdev or udev.

Answer (score 1):

[`devtmpfs` always sets permissions to `0600` and makes it up to `udev` (or whatever runs after it) to maintain them](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DEVTMPFS.html). [Its source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/devtmpfs.c#L82) confirms there's no way to override this explicitly (`tty` device driver [overrides `mode` unconditionally in some cases](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L3533)).

Assuming you're using the [Buildroot's default `busybox` as `init`](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_init_system), there's a way to do this with the following *additional* line in [`busybox`'s `inittab`](http://spblinux.de/2.0/doc/init.html) <sub>(additional=must be present in addition to the essential lines (or their replacements) that are implied when there's no `inittab` - as they are no longer implied then there is)</sub>:

```
::sysinit:<path_to_your_script>
```

with the script calling `chown` and `chmod` in loop.

But, it's better to handle this within the existing `/etc/init.d/rcS` (which is also run by BusyBox's `init` at `sysinit` by default).

As you can see from the [stock buildroot's `/etc/init.d/rcS`](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/system/skeleton/etc/init.d/rcS), all you need to do is create a script `/etc/init.d/S<whatever>.sh` (where "whatever" places it into the desired position in the `/etc/init.d/S??*` output) with your commands:

```sh
for tty in /dev/tty*; do
    chown root:dialout "$tty"
    chmod ug+rw "$tty"   #do not touch other bits
done
unset tty
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: choose `mdev` as your device manager, and use the `tty` group instead of `dialout`.

The kernel's `devtmpfs` creates device nodes with a default name, owner and permissions. It also sends out a `uevent` when the node is created, which allows a uevent handler to change the name, ownership or permissions, or do anything else it wants. Previously this was called the hotplug system, but nowadays it's much more generic.

Buildroot offers the choice between three uevent handlers: `mdev`, which is part of busybox, `eudev` which is a standalone `udev` fork, and `udev` which is part of the `systemd` init system. These handlers are configured with rules files that specify what to do with a specific type of device when it appears.

For your specific need, `mdev` is the best choice since it is very simple, easy to understand, doesn't take up much space, and the default configuration is sufficient. In Buildroot's menuconfig, go to *System configuration* → */dev management* and select *Dynamic using mdev*. Then rebuild your root filesystem. It will now be populated with the `mdev` binary (part of `busybox`), an init script to start it, and a default rules file in `/etc/mdev.conf`. This default file contains:

```
tty[0-9]*       root:tty 660
```

This means that the `tty` devices will get their group changed to `tty` and their permissions to group read and write. So you can just make sure that the logged in user belongs to the `tty` group, and Bob's your uncle.

If the default `mdev.conf` file is not sufficient for you (for instance, if you really need the group to be `dialout`), then you can create a filesystem overlay, copy `package/busybox/mdev.conf` to `/etc/mdev.conf` and modify it as needed. Full documentation on the `mdev.conf` format can be found [in the busybox sources](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/plain/docs/mdev.txt).